# Procedurally generated Ground for 3D printed model bases

Tags: modeling, add-on, geometry, procedural

Is there a simple\easy way to procedural generate terrain in Blender that I use to create 100 slightly different 3D printed model bases for a WH40K army?

Maybe something that makes rocks, or even just makes the ground never?

Comment: Have you tried the ANT landscape addon?

Comment: any reference of your expectations?

Comment: I've not heard of the ANT addon, I will give it a go.

Comment: No references or expectations as of yet, I don't know what's possible so I don't know what's asking too much or what's really easy.

Comment: A cursory glance says that ANT is good for renders but not so much for 3D printing.